# Don't show (partial) comments from nominations I can't view

Tags: bug, comments, moderator-election

On the website, my inbox shows the most recent 1 comment received on my nomination for the moderator election (which was deleted).

It doesn't attribute the comment to anyone in particular, and clicking on it won't let me view the comment to see who left it, or see any other comments that were left on my nomination.

(The Android app's inbox shows all the comments and the full content on them, although I still can't reply to them or see who left them.)

Comment: FWIW, you can view the comments in their entirety [on your responses tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble?tab=responses)

Comment: Thanks. The link in the inbox going there would be helpful.

Comment: Also, we *all* love cryptofascist parodies. But we also take elections somewhat seriously; a bit of humor is one thing, but if the sole purpose of a nomination appears to be a joke, that penalizes other nominees (and potentially blocks people from nominating entirely) - hence the *multiple* "is this a joke?" comments (which never saw a response...)

Comment: Whether or not you're elected isn't my call (or yours, once you've nominated). But we both owe it to the voters to give them legit choices; a moderator who stands without intending to serve is a waste of their time and votes.

Comment: Well, don't tell me; tell the folks who read your nomination and were not convinced. Or just write a more convincing nomination.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Complaints about this particular situation aside, this is a legitimate bug; comments under election nominations are pretty broken. To summarize:

- Links often don't work properly *even when the nomination is still alive*. Hence the absence of the permalink in the timestamp that's present on all other comments.
- Because links don't work properly, flags left moderators confused searching for the flagged text; hence the removal of the flag link.
- It's not possible to vote on comments (because showing the vote link would require showing the flag link as well).

Broken, broken, held-together-with-duct-tape-and-twine broken. And here's another example of that.

So... Thanks for the bug report.